# Question about designing a function for printing a frame

Tags: c

Ok, I so i've been confused on this in the picture: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0BEa.png)

That means that am i supposed to have the quote surrounded by frame like this for the function framed quote()?:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void quote ();
void framed_quote();

int main(){
    quote();
    framed_quote();
    return 0; 
} 

void quote (){
 printf("\"I'm not sleeping, I'm inspecting the inside of my eyelids\" - Hawkeye 
 Pierce\n");
}

void framed_quote(){

printf("/*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~******~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\
\n");
printf("|*");
printf("\"I'm not sleeping, I'm inspecting the inside of my eyelids\" - Hawkeye 
Pierce");
printf("*|\n");

printf("\\*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~******~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*
/\n") 
;
}
```

But why does my output look like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NRd1.png) Can anyone tell me how to have an orgainzed function frame like the output below?

```
/*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~******~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*\
|*"I’m not sleeping, I’m inspecting the inside of my eyelids" - Hawkeye Pierce*|
\*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~******~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*/
```

for the framed quote()?

Edit:
Why does it look like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8ccR.png)? Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the assignment is asking for a function that will frame *any* quote. You have to adjust the frame size based on the length of the quote

Answer (score 2):

`\` is an escape sequence character in printf, so you need to use an escape sequence character in front of it if you want to use it in a printed string.

**Example**

```
printf("\\*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~******~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*/\n");
```

Comment: Wait could you tell me why my output looks disorgainzed? How do i make the line 18 to go down?

Comment: You escaped the newline at the end of line 17, so you need to add another \ before \n

Comment: Is their any links to this i can learn more about if possible...?

Comment: I’ve used [this](http://cplusplus.com/) website a lot. It has documentation and examples for all the functions in the C standard library. Good luck.